# Is there an out-of-universe reason for Brandy Ledford kicking Lexa Doig to the back seat?

Tags: andromeda

I have an older cousin who's major *Andromeda* fan so I've seen quite a few episodes but I can't figure out why Doyle replaces Rommie.

Did Lexa want out but had contract obligations?

Did she annoy the producer(s)?

For season 5 of *Andromeda* Rommie's character has been reduced to something akin to Gwen DeMarco's alter ego Tawny Madison in *Galaxy Quest*. That is, she has become a parody of herself.

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lexa Doig gave birth to a daughter in September 2004, during the final season of Andromeda. Rather than "drama", I always assumed this was the explanation for her reduced role.

The [Andromeda wiki](http://andromeda.wikia.com/wiki/Rommie) seems to support this:

> Due to Lexa Doig's pregnancy during the filming of the fifth season of Andromeda, writers re-wrote part of the season finale so her character could be excluded from most of Season 5. The character Doyle was written to replace her during this time. Rommie's new body is thicker and bustier than her old body, due to the physiological changes that occur in a woman during pregnancy and child birth, and upon being asked by Dylan how she felt, Rommie answered "Sturdy."

Comment: Accepting your answer but I note that *IMDB* rates none of Season 5 in the top 1/3 of all episodes and only one or two in the top 1/2. -- Rommie's absence was, to me, the most obvious lack in the final season. Early on I was keen on the possibilities for 3-way conversations/arguments with herself - meaning **Rommie** (the android), **Andromeda** (the hologram) and **Andromeda Ascendant** (the 2D video presence/ship's computer voice-over). In general it seems the 22 episode **Win to Exit TV Trope** nature of Season 5 had numerous weaknesses and the lack of **Rommie** was, for me, the lowlight.

Comment: @user23715 It was so long ago I can't actually remember much of the show.

Comment: Sure, not much to remember. None of the campy funness of the *Stargate* universe and no real attempt to make the science with much verisimilitude like the *Trek* universe. Initially it had a sort of *Firefly* feel to it but that was gone before Season 3. I did see at least half a dozen bit actors that made it over to *Battlestar Galactica* as major players. But mostly meh :\